# PHP: Why won't the program compare values as equal when it prints them with equal values

Tags: php, integer, equality

I have this code for a system:

```
//get new data from text fields
$i = 0;
$data = array();
while ($i < 7){
    $data[$i] = $_POST['t'.$i];
    $i++;
}

//get the ID to use in the MySQL database query
$id=$data[0];

//get the existing integer from MySQL database
$query="SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ID='$id';";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$mem=mysql_result($result, 0, 'Member');

//print to see if it's equal
echo 'Does '.$mem.'='.$data[1].'?<br>';

//check equality
if ($mem != $data[1]){
    echo "I'm not supposed to exist";
}
```

The $data[0] is the unique id for that database table and $data[1] is what we're trying to get.

The code prints `$mem` as `999999.` Same with `$data[0]`, `999999.` But for some reason, when I pass them through the `if` statement, They are not equal.

Comment: [`MySQL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) (_mysql_*_ functions) extension is [***deprecated***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). I suggest to use [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (_mysqli_*_ functions) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: Your if statement compares $data[1], not $data[0].
And escape your single-quotes inside echo. Or use: `echo "I'm not supposed to exist";`

Comment: This code should get a syntax error because of the unescaped quote, so it shouldn't even execute.

Comment: @Barmar But it "prints" somehow... Probably reproduction of issue.

Comment: In your code you say `$data[1]`, but in your question you say `$data[0]`. Which is it? Please show your _real_ code, because you're probably missing something when you try to reproduce it here.

Comment: Hey, sorry, had a little made a little error with the quotes. I also cleared up what the values in data are

Comment: Show `var_dump($mem, $data[1])`.

Comment: $data[1] is what I'm looking for. The reason why I used $data[0] is because it's the address of an object. Basically the object is supposed to belong to a person's id, and that's $data[1]

Comment: Might be encoding, if there are `characters` instead of `digits`. Are mysql client and php encodings are compatible?

Comment: look at my answer below and cast it to numbers. That is why I don't like php. If you compare numbers be sure they are compared as numbers in this particular case as integers.

Comment: string(6) "999999" string(6) "999999" – the output of var_dump($mem, $data[1]);

Comment: @Robert Podwika there is no difference. OP comparing strings, (`$_GET` - strings, `mysql_result` - strings).

Comment: they may be difference in encoding. String may be encoded in various types, why don't you check my solution? If you don't want to cast them use binary safe comparing function strcmp();

Comment: @RobertPodwika, I casted it to int, but it still compared as unequal

Answer (score 2):

Cast them to int

```
if ((int)$mem != (int)$data[1]){
    echo "I'm not supposed to exist";
}
```

you write data[0] is equal to $mem and you compare $data[1]